# No runtime errors showing in debugger for custom winforms control yet console.WriteLine shows it has stopped

Tags: c#, .net

I've created a custom charting control for windows forms and I'm now trying to debug it since it's not working.

I've had to switch to Console application type, and write Console.WriteLine statements everywhere to find what's going on. In this case my code tries to access a negative index of an array. Yet NOTHING pops up with the debugger. Instead the application just shows a big red X and stops drawing/calculating/ect as proven by my console.writeline statements.

My project was started as a Windows Forms application. It consists of a few classes along with a ChartControl (my control) inheriting from user control. And I'm using the default form to test it that came with the Windows Forms application.

When I debug it just runs the windows form which always stays in focus with no pop ups or notifications coming from visual studio. The Locals and Call Stack in visual studio remain faded out / empty. Yet I know for a fact that the application is dead-stop in its tracks after trying to use a negative index value. Sorry I don't know what to do, or how to see what is going on.

Does anyone know what is going on and how I can get debugging information?

Update:

I've found a window called output that seems to show stuff from the debugger. And I get:

"A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in....(Name.exe)"

However as you can see it does not show the location or anything like that. Interesting.....

Comment: I would not expect a windows forms control to work in a console app. Instead of Console.WriteLine(), try using the System.Diagnostics.Trace class. You can just change every instance of Console.WriteLine() to Trace.WriteLine(), and the output will show in your debugger window.

Comment: Thanks @JoelCoehoorn, I've done that but I'm not getting any of the WriteLines to show up. What exact window should I be looking at? Also I made sure to put one Trace.WriteLine right at start of application to make sure it would get called. It's fine if you don't answer, I can also find what window myself. Thanks!

Comment: NVM I've found the window thanks!

Comment: OP: In that case please write the answer in and mark it solved for others!

Answer (score 0):

In VS, select Debug menu > Exceptions... and ensure the correct types are selected.